Kelly Criterion in real trading
Kelly Criterion seems to me very stylized and even unrealistic framework (given its assumptions), which has extremely limited applied use. I was wondering whether you are aware of any real-life trading strategies which are backed by Kelly Criterion? If so, could you please discuss a bit how Kelly Criterion was applied?

This should be a comment, but I do not have enough reputation. The following facts may be of interest to you. In Thorp, E. O. (2011) 509–523, it is claimed that Samuelson (yes that Samuelson) has shown that the Kelly criterion will lead to a loss under the utilities:
$$H(W)=-1/W$$
$$T(W)=\sqrt{W}$$
In fact following the Kelly criterion will lead the sum of losses to be infinite! I have not verified these computations and the manuscript is filled with a lot of typesetting errors.
However, Samuelson was a very staunch critic of the Kelly criterion. In fact, he once wrote and published a peer-reviewed paper criticizing the Kelly criterion with all, but one, single syllable words to prove his point.

Thank you for this. I was wondering do you have references for Samuelson's papers?

If you google scholar Samuelson Kelly, you will find numerous published papers where he debates others on this (with many sample calculations). However, Samuelson, Paul A. PNAS 68.10 (1971): 2493-2496 may be of interest to you.

I can see, thank you!

When reading Systematic Trading by Carver, he doesn't exactly explain the mathematics behind using Kelly criterion. He just states that Kelly criterion is used in volatility targeting.
How he uses it in volatility targeting is via the Sharpe ratio. Say for example you computed an annualized expected return of 8.0%, then you would like to keep the Sharpe ratio at 1.0 and set the volatility target that does so. Therefore, the annualized volatility acceptable would be:
$$Volatility\,Target = \frac{Expected\,Return}{Sharpe\,Ratio} = \frac{8.0\%}{1} = 8.0\%$$
But then he goes onto say that this is not very good because risk itself is not symmetric and instead asymmetric, so a better use for Kelly criterion is half Kelly criterion instead, which becomes:
$$Volatility\,Target = 0.5*\frac{Expected\,Return}{Sharpe\,Ratio} = 0.5*\frac{8.0\%}{1} = 4.0\%$$

There are articles on the internet where people have modified the kelly criterion framework so that it can be used for position sizing when making bets on individual stocks. I haven't read them carefully and don't know if the techniques are helpful but the articles are out there. If you need help finding them, let me know and I'll try to help.

I also don't know if the same techniques are used in industry or even by these individuals. Sometimes an article is just that: an article.

@EvanSemet the whole point is about volatility targeting to set your level of risk. If you decided to use full Kelly criterion and set your Sortino at 1, the volatility target must reflect the downside risk. I don't really understand how you can use Sortino if you don't get to use downside risk as an input in the first place.

KaiSqDist: On re-reading the question, it's not clear whether Sane was referring to volatility targeting or position sizing ? They are related but not really that similar.  Maybe he meant any application of Kelly ?

@markleeds it is any general application of Kelly criterion to trading.

Yes, I am interested in real-life application of Kelly Criterion, in general.

gotcha but it's probably going to be unlikely to get feedback regarding real-life applications. Your best chance is probably just to infer from papers like the ones I mentioned earlier.

Yes, I will try to capitalize on papers, but as you mentioned sometimes papers are just written for the sake of publication. Thank you!

@Sane Can you accept my answer or give me an upvote if you feel it helped? Thanks!

Sure, @KaiSqDist! Thank you!

I remember hearing Marcos López de Prado say Kelly can be used after applying meta labeling. I don't remember if it was in his book or from a lecture he was giving.
I myself have strategies that utilizes just that. Using the model's confidence levels and Kelly to determine my bet size. From my testing, I went from a Sortino of 1.7 to a 3 using this method.
Robert Carver's blog mentions using Kelly also.

Typo, wanted to say Carver mentions using Kelly.
